# Zero is ignored as a value in XslCompiledTransform

Tags: c#, xslt

I have the following issue:
I have the following code:

```
private void ApplyTransform(XsltArgumentList arguments, out string output) 
{
    using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter()) 
    {
        XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
        m_xslTransform.Transform(m_rootNode, arguments, xmlTextWriter);
        xmlTextWriter.Close();
        output = stringWriter.ToString();
    }
}
```

One of the argument is zero (double zero) and I expect it to be seen in the output XML, but the argument does not present in XML at all.

The XSL part:

```
  <xsl:if test="$Argument">
    <xsl:attribute name="Argument">
      <xsl:value-of select="$Argument" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
```

Could you tell me what I am missing?

Comment: Note: `<xsl:if test="$Argument>` is missing the closing quote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $Argument is a number and it equals zero, then the test in

```
<xsl:if test="$Argument">
```

returns false. See:http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-boolean

---

### Edit:

You can use

```
<xsl:if test="string($Argument)">
```

to test that the variable is not empty, or:

```
<xsl:if test="number($Argument)=number($Argument)">
```

to test that the variable is a number, incl. zero.

Comment: Thank you! Any ideas how to get 0?

Comment: Either remove the test, or apply a different one. What is the purpose of the test?

Comment: To check, if the argument, which is supposed to be added to the output XML, is in the list of arguments. If not - it should not be added.